# Not show notification in status bar if app is running

Tags: android, service, notifications

I am implementing an android app that uses a service which posts notifications. I only want to display the notifications after the user has closed the app. Is it possible to not show notification in status bar if app is running?

Answer (score 1):

You can work it around:

You could notify your service when the app has started (from the app), so it can remove the `Notification` instance.

The same, when your application has been closed by the user, before explicitly finishing the current activity, the app will notify the service to show the notification again.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  I can't put the code to notify the service in Activity callbacks like onStart() or onPause() because these may be called on other circumstances like navigation from one activity to another. onCreate() may not be called if the user presses home button directly instead of back button and later restores the app.